# Cell-wise calculations in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what I'm sure is a fundamental lack of understanding about how dataframes work in Python. I am sure this is an easy question, but I have looked everywhere and can't find a good explanation. I am trying to understand why sometimes dataframe calculations seem to run on a row-by-row (or cell by cell) basis, and sometimes seem to run for an entire column... For example:

```
data = {'Name':['49-037-23094', '49-029-21476', '49-029-20812', '49-041-21318'], 'Depth':[20, 21, 7, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

Which gives:

```
           Name  Depth
0  49-037-23094     20
1  49-029-21476     21
2  49-029-20812      7
3  49-041-21318     18
```

Now I know I can do:

```
df['DepthDouble']=df['Depth']*2
```

And get:

```
           Name  Depth  DepthDouble
0  49-037-23094     20           40
1  49-029-21476     21           42
2  49-029-20812      7           14
3  49-041-21318     18           36
```

Which is what I would expect. But this doesn't always work, and I'm trying to understand why. For example, I am trying to run this code to modify the name:

```
df['newName']=''.join(re.findall('\d',str(df['Name'])))
```

which gives:

```
           Name  Depth  DepthDouble  \
0  49-037-23094     20           40   
1  49-029-21476     21           42   
2  49-029-20812      7           14   
3  49-041-21318     18           36   

                                        newName  
0  04903723094149029214762490292081234904121318  
1  04903723094149029214762490292081234904121318  
2  04903723094149029214762490292081234904121318  
3  04903723094149029214762490292081234904121318
```

So it is taking all the values in my name column, removing the dashes, and concatenating them. Of course, I'd just like it to be a new name column exactly the same as the original "Name" column, but without the dashes.

So, can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here? I Don't understand why sometimes Dataframe calculations for one column are done row by row (e.g., the Depth Doubled column) and sometimes Python seems to take all values in the entire column and run the calculation (e.g., the newName column).

Surely the way to get around this isn't by making a loop for every index in the df to force it to run individually for each row for a given column?

Comment: are you looking for `df['Name'].str.findall('\d').str.join('')` ? which would yeild same as `df['Name'].str.replace('-','')` for the sample

Comment: Great question! Please include an example of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output you're looking for is:

```
Name    Depth   newName
0   49-037-23094    20  4903723094
1   49-029-21476    21  4902921476
2   49-029-20812    7   4902920812
3   49-041-21318    18  4904121318
```

The way to get this is:

```py
df['newName']=df['Name'].map(lambda name: ''.join(re.findall('\d', name)))
```

`map` is like `apply` but specifically for Series objects. Since you're applying to only the Name column you are operating on a Series.

If the lambda part is confusing, an equivalent way to write it is:

```py
def find_digits(name):
    return ''.join(re.findall('\d', name))

df['newName']=df['Name'].map(find_digits)
```

The equivalent operation in traditional for loops is:

```py
newNameSeries = pd.Series(name='newName')
for name in df['Name']:
    newNameSeries = newNameSeries.append(pd.Series(''.join(re.findall('\d', name))), ignore_index=True)

pd.concat([df, newNameSeries], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'newName'})
```

While there might be a slightly cleaner way to do the loop, you can see how much simpler the first approach is compared to trying to use for-loops. It's also faster. As you already have indicated you know, avoid for loops when using pandas.

Comment: Connor - thank you so much! "map" is exactly what I have been looking for. I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that with `str(df['Name'])` you are converting the entire `Name`-column of your DataFrame to one single string. What you want to do instead is to use one of pandas' own methods for strings, which will be applied to every single element of the column.

For example, you could use pandas' `replace` method for strings:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['49-037-23094', '49-029-21476', '49-029-20812', '49-041-21318'],    'Depth':[20, 21, 7, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df['newName'] = df['Name'].str.replace('-', '')
```